# Unable to animate movement of textbox2 upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have a form with 2 `button`s and 2 `textarea`s. On loading, I want to show only `section1` (button, text area) and `section2` button. On clicking `section2` , I want to hide `section1` text area, show `section2` `text area` and gradually move it to top of the screen where `section1` `text area` was (as it `section2` `text area` is going upwards). On clicking `section1` button, I want to hide `section2` text area and show transition of `section1` `textarea` growing downwards.

I have written the following code so far. While I am able to show/hide the two sections, I am unable to create animation.

```js
function showSection1HideOthers(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  console.log("will show question", target);
  var elToShow = $("#section1");
  var elToHide = $("#section2");
  elToShow.addClass("uncollapsed");
  elToShow.removeClass("collapsed");
  elToHide.addClass("collapsed");
  elToHide.removeClass("uncollapsed");
}

function showSection2HideOthers(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  console.log("will show question", target);
  var elToShow = $("#section2");
  var elToHide = $("#section1");
  elToShow.addClass("uncollapsed");
  elToShow.removeClass("collapsed");
  elToHide.addClass("collapsed");
  elToHide.removeClass("uncollapsed");
}
```

```css
.collapsed {
  display: none;
  animation-name: contract;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

.uncollapsed {
  display: block;
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    display: none;
    height: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


@keyframes contract {
  0% {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    display: none;
    height: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="new-form" onSubmit="addPracticeQuestion()" novalidate>
  <div>
    <!-- label and small in same line. select in a new line, thus enclosed select in a div-->
    <button type="button" class="unselected-button" id="section1-collapsable-button" onclick="showSection1HideOthers(event)">Section1</button>
    <div id="section1">
      <div class="section1-div" id="description-div">
        <textarea id="section1-description" type="text" rows="4">Section 1</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- transition to this only after the question has been filled correctly-->
    <button type="button" class="unselected-button" id="section2-collapsable-button" onclick="showSection2HideOthers(event)">Section2</button>
    <div class="collapsed" id="section2">
      <div id="section2-div">
        <textarea id="section2-description" type="text" rows="4"> Section 2</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is see that you are using jQuery so you can use the `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` methods.

Read more here -> [`slideUp`](https://api.jquery.com/slideup/) You can add also options to these methods. Like duration, easing and so on

Also I made some changes to your HTML/jQ code.

Use a common class for buttons (`unselected-button`) and select them with jquery and then add a click function on them.

Add common class to the sections. I used `.section`

Then, select the section which comes after the clicked button ( when clicking on Submit1 will select section1 , same for the second or even if you have more button/sections ) and show it with `slideUp()`

Then select all the sections which are not the selected one ( the one selected at the previous step ) and hide them with `slideDown()`

```js
var button = $('.unselected-button'); // both buttons
$(button).on('click', function() {
  var elToShow = $(this).next('.section');
  var elToHide = $('.section').not(elToShow);
  elToShow.slideDown()
  elToHide.slideUp()
})
```

```css
#section2 {
  display:none
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="new-form" onSubmit="addPracticeQuestion()" novalidate>
  <div>
    <!-- label and small in same line. select in a new line, thus enclosed select in a div-->
    <button type="button" class="unselected-button" id="section1-collapsable-button">Section1</button>
    <div id="section1" class="section">
      <div class="section1-div" id="description-div">
        <textarea id="section1-description" type="text" rows="4">Section 1</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- transition to this only after the question has been filled correctly-->
    <button type="button" class="unselected-button" id="section2-collapsable-button">Section2</button>
    <div class="section" id="section2" >
      <div id="section2-div">
        <textarea id="section2-description" type="text" rows="4"> Section 2</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Many thanks. The code works fine. I'll read the code and I might come back to you if I have questions.

Comment: @ManuChadha glad I could help. Cheers ! :D

Comment: one comment - what was I doing wrong when I was using pure `.js` to animate?

Comment: No. You were using a combination of JS and jquery to select and add/remove classes. And css for animation. The JS/jquery was correct ( although could've been made more  ' optimal ' ) but the CSS animation was not correct ( you would've needed to use animation-fill-mode and translate:scale )  But, If you already have jQuery in your project ( although I don't necessarily recommend it ) it's a good idea to use what jQuery has to offer.